# Grafana import API will not return a proper dashboard ID (in response)after importing a new dashboard using API

Tags: grafana-api

While importing the dashboard, API is not returning proper dashboard ID.

For all the dashboard ID it provides `id` as `0`

If I check the dashboard using *Chrome Devtools > Network* tab, I'm able to get some id (in increment order).

**What Grafana version are you using?**

5.2.0-beta3 (previously using 5.1.4)

**What datasource are you using?**

InfluxDB

**What OS are you running grafana on?**

Windows 10 Pro

**What did you do?**

Imported the dashboard using Grafana API

**What was the expected result?**

Should be able to import the dashboard and as response it should return a dashboard ID

**What happened instead?**

Able to import the dashboard but not getting proper dashboard ID. For all dashboard it gives `ID=0`

```js
import requests
url='http://admin:admin@localhost:3000/api/dashboards/import'
data='''{
  "dashboard": {}
  "folderId": 8,
  "overwrite": false
}'''
headers={"Content-Type": 'application/json'}
response = requests.post(url, data=data,headers=headers)
print(response)
print(response.status_code)
print (response.text)
```

**Response**

```js
Response [200]
200
{
    "pluginId": "",
    "title": "Template dfsad",
    "imported": true,
    "importedUri": "db/template-dfsad",
    "importedUrl": "/d/uid1098/template-dfsad",
    "slug": "",
    "dashboardId": 0,
    "folderId": 8,
    "importedRevision": 1,
    "revision": 1,
    "description": "",
    "path": "",
    "removed": false
}
```

Comment: You better ask this in some grapana community